# Python Open Error for Absolute Filepath from Command Prompt in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, command-prompt, spyder

I have the Anaconda3 distribution for Python 3.6 on Windows 10. I am making the following call from the command window to a script that will create and write to a text file:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python C:\Users\shawn\Documents\Google_Maps_Drive_Times\Commute_Times.py
```

And get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shawn\Documents\Google_Maps_Drive_Times\Commute_Times.py", line 97, in <module>
    with open(ff, 'w') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\Daily_Trip_Times\\Commute_Times_05-26-18_1558.txt'
```

The strange part is that the code runs perfectly fine when I run it using the Spyder IDE. Even more strange is that the code works from the command prompt if I add

```
ff = ff.replace('\\','\')
```

However, that then breaks the functionality in Spyder, as I would expect. I also tried using backslashes, but get the same error as with "\\".

Note that I have made some simple scripts to verify that Python is working and

```
where python
```

provides

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

as I would expect. Any help in understanding the path directory nuances between Spyder and the command prompt would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ff = ff.replace('\\','\')` is in the python program? `'\'` isn't valid syntax. The program shouldn't run.

Comment: Does the file exist? Its not normal for data to go into \windows\system32 like that. Since we don't know what's in your python script its hard to guess what is going on. Can you write a few-line python script that demonstrates the problem? Post it and the stack trace here.

Comment: Since the working directory is "C:\WINDOWS\system32", the most likely explanation is that `ff` is based on a relative path. Probably your mistake is assuming the working directory is the script path. That's probably the case when you run the script from Spyder, but a bad assumption in general.

Comment: @tdelaney Sorry that wasn't clear about the {ff.replace} line, but that is added into the python script after ff is defined as shown in the error. It gets the script to work when being called from the command prompt for some reason. ff is an absolute path as you can see in the error. It is {'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\Daily_Trip_Times\\Commute_Times_05-26-18_1558.txt'}. The script works when it is called from the command line and I replace the double forward slashes with single ones. That breaks functionality in Spyder though.

Comment: But its invalid syntax and the program will not run. I can see the path in the error message... that's why I asked you whether the file really exists. You haven't shown the code that builds the file name - that is likely where the error is. See @erykson 's comment.

Comment: Ugh, you guys were very correct about the working directory being a function of a relative path. Not my finest hour here. The filename was built from os.getcwd() when it should have been built from os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(\_\_file\_\_)). Thank you for your help.